# How to inherit shell's running ssh-agent with net::ss::perl::agent

Tags: perl-module

Is there a way to use the already running ssh-agent in a bash session with net::ss::perl::agent ultimately so I don't have to setup keys again with net::ss::perl? I don't see any examples anywhere. I keep seeing a way to create a new agent but not a way to connect it to the shell? Thanks

Edit:

I should explain that I can't use Net::OpenSSH since i have to work with commercial SSH servers and the openssh client doesn't work properly with it(I've tested this).

Comment: Take a look at [Net::SSH::Perl::Agent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl::Agent)... I must admit I don't see how it would work, but the answer might be in there somewhere :-) If you figure it out post it as an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 0):

Use Net::OpenSSH instead of Net::SSH::Perl

Comment: thanks but I can't use Net::OpenSSH since I have to work with commercial SSH2 servers and can't use an openssh client.

Answer (score 0):

For me it just works. As long as the environment variables SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID are defined in the shell and point to a valid ssh-agent process Net::SSH::Perl::Agent will be able to talk to the agent. There are scripts that make this easier on the internet.